# How to get code coverage in unit test if((Trigger.isUpdate && rcrd[0].Role__c <> Trigger.oldMap.get(rsp.Id).Role__c)

Tags: unit-test

For this trigger, I have a test class but I need help getting coverage for this if statement

```
if((Trigger.isUpdate && rcrd[0].Role__c <> Trigger.oldMap.get(rsp.Id).Role__c) || Trigger.isInsert)  trigger.new[0].addError('A contact with the role "'+rsp.Role__c+'" already Exist. Only the role "Other" may be assigned to multiple Key Staff People.');
```

This is the trigger

```
trigger trgr_Check_Duplicate_Roles on Key_Staff_People__c (before insert,before update) {


    for (Key_Staff_People__c rsp: Trigger.new) 
        {


            List <Key_Staff_People__c> rcrd = [SELECT Contact__c, Role__c FROM Key_Staff_People__c 
                                                WHERE Contact__c = :rsp.Contact__c AND Role__c = :rsp.Role__c];


            if (rcrd.size() > 0)
            {
                if (rsp.Role__c <> Null && rsp.Role__c <> 'Other' )
                {
                    if((Trigger.isUpdate && rcrd[0].Role__c <> Trigger.oldMap.get(rsp.Id).Role__c) || Trigger.isInsert)  trigger.new[0].addError('A contact with the role "'+rsp.Role__c+'" already Exist. Only the role "Other" may be assigned to multiple Key Staff People.');                    
                }
            }
        }
}
```

This is the unit test

```
@isTest 
public class trgr_Check_Duplicate_Roles_Test {
    @testSetup static void test_DataSetup() 
    {

        Id acctRTypeId = [SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE sObjectType='Account' AND Name='FIGS Federation Account' LIMIT 1].ID;
        Id contactRTypeId = [SELECT Id FROM RecordType WHERE sObjectType='Contact' AND Name='Contact' LIMIT 1].ID;

        List<Account> acctList = new List<Account>();
        List<Contact> contactList = new List<Contact>();
        List<Key_Staff_People__c> kpList = new List<Key_Staff_People__c>();

           Account a1 = new Account(Name='AccountTest1',RecordTypeId=acctRTypeId); 
           Account a2 = new Account(Name='AccountTest2',RecordTypeId=acctRTypeId);  
           Account a3 = new Account(Name='AccountTest3',RecordTypeId=acctRTypeId);    
           acctList.add(a1);
           acctList.add(a2);
           acctList.add(a3);
           insert acctList;

           Contact c1 = new Contact(FirstName='firstName',LastName='ContactTest1',RecordTypeId=contactRTypeId,Constituent_Code__c='Donor',AccountId=acctList[0].id);
           Contact c2 = new Contact(FirstName='firstName',LastName='ContactTest2',RecordTypeId=contactRTypeId,Constituent_Code__c='Donor',AccountId=acctList[1].id); 
           Contact c3 = new Contact(FirstName='firstName',LastName='ContactTest3',RecordTypeId=contactRTypeId,Constituent_Code__c='Donor',AccountId=acctList[2].id);  
           contactList.add(c1);
           contactList.add(c2);
           contactList.add(c3);
           insert contactList;


           Key_Staff_People__c bm = new Key_Staff_People__c(Contact__c = c1.id, First_Name__c='FName1', Last_Name__c='LName1',role__c = 'Relationship Manager');
           Key_Staff_People__c bm2 = new Key_Staff_People__c(Contact__c = c2.id,First_Name__c='FName2', Last_Name__c='LName2',role__c = 'Relationship Manager');
           Key_Staff_People__c bm3 = new Key_Staff_People__c(Contact__c = c3.id,First_Name__c='FName3', Last_Name__c='LName3',role__c = 'Other');        

           // Insert 
            insert bm;
            insert bm2; 
            insert bm3;
            Key_Staff_People__c bm4 = new Key_Staff_People__c(id= bm3.id);
            update bm4;


    }

    static testMethod void unitTest () {
        Test.startTest();

            List <Key_Staff_People__c> rcrd = [SELECT Contact__c, Role__c FROM Key_Staff_People__c WHERE Role__c ='Relationship Manager' ];
        if(rcrd.size()>0)
        {
            if (rcrd[0].Role__c <> Null && rcrd[0].Role__c <> 'Other')
            {

            }
        }

        Test.StopTest();
    }
}
```

Comment: If you try to cover this line, you will end up getting an error in your test method and your test method might fail.

Comment: @Abhijeet The `addError` will appear in the test as a `DmlException` that the test can `catch` and so expect/handle as necessary.

Comment: Yes exactly.We need to use try catch for this and then this can be covered

Comment: I suggest you work on fixing your trigger's problems before you worry about the unit test. Your code could cause problems once it's deployed to production.

Comment: Everyone seems to be on the same page with this but me.  Sorry but I need more info. Can you explain what the trigger's problems are and where it can fail? I tested it and it does what I was asked to do. What do I need to fix? And how to setup the try catch?

Comment: @ApexN-u-b You trigger isn't good for the bulk case. Insert 101 Key_Staff_People__c in a test method and you will hit the query governor limit because you have a query inside the loop. You are setting the error on the first row not the current row. Google to find examples of catching DmlException in a test.

Comment: Ok I understand now Keith. BTW, I put that one line in a try catch  in the trigger and it didn't cover it. Was I supposed to do this in the test? If so, where?

Comment: The try/catch should be in the test and the test needs to insert or update the data in a way that makes the trigger add the error that then results in the exception being thrown.

Comment: Yes. It worked. Thank you. If you want, make it answer and I can check it off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The try/catch of DmlException should be in the test and the test needs to insert or update the data in a way that makes the trigger add the error that then results in the exception being thrown from the trigger and caught in the test.

Comment: Now that it's working. I am open to making it bulkified and professional-like. Can you give me a suggestion how to do this?

Comment: @ApexN-u-b Best that you Google "apex bulkification" and read the various posts you will find. With 2 fields ANDed adding a formula field that concatenates the 2 may help. Suggest you invest several hours of your own time and try to work it out. Then if you are still stuck post a new question with your best effort at it in the question.